# When I Use function wp_insert_term() function it gives me Invalid taxonomy object

Tags: terms

if(isset($_REQUEST['review_add'])){

```
$rw_es_name = $_REQUEST['rw_es_name'];
$rw_cl_name = $_REQUEST['rw_cl_name'];
$rw_cl_email = $_REQUEST['rw_cl_email'];
$rw_cl_review = $_REQUEST['rw_cl_review']; 
$postthumbnailid = $_REQUEST['postthumbnailid']; 

$rw_term = term_exists($rw_es_name,'review_texanomies',0);

// Create state if it doesn't exist
if ( !$rw_term ) {
    $defaults = array( 'alias_of' => '', 'description' => '', 'parent' => 0, 'slug' => '');
    $rw_term = wp_insert_term($rw_es_name,'review_texanomies',$defaults );

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rw_term);
echo '</pre>';
die();

$tex = $rw_term['term_taxonomy_id'];

$defaults = array(
    'post_status' => 'pending',
    'post_type' => 'review',
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'ping_status' => 'open',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'menu_order' => 0,
    'to_ping' => '',
    'pinged' => '',
    'post_password' => '',
    'guid' => '',
    'post_content_filtered' => '',
    'post_excerpt' => '',
    'import_id' => 0,
    'post_title' => $rw_es_name,
    'post_content' => $rw_cl_review,
    //'tax_input'=> array('review_texanomies' => $tex)
    'post_category' => array('review_texanomies' => $tex)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($defaults, $wp_error);
//wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append );

if ($post_id) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'rw_es_name', $rw_es_name);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'rw_cl_name', $rw_cl_name);
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'rw_cl_email', $rw_cl_email); 
    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $postthumbnailid );
    //wp_set_object_terms($post_id , $rw_es_name, 'review_texanomies', true);
}
```

}

It gives me output like

WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [invalid_taxonomy] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Invalid taxonomy
                )

```
    )

[error_data] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Or when i m using term_exists() it gives me id of terms..

So how  wp_insert_term() function gives this type of error? when terms already gives out put?... please help mefor resolve this problem.

Comment: either you register your taxonomy on the wrong hook, or you try to run this code before the hook that registers your taxonomy. please add the context of where you execute this code, and add your code that registers your taxonomy.

Comment: Looks like a spelling mistake to me - are you sure review_texanomies is right?

Comment: Look my Custom post type texonomy Url: http://elektra-escorts.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=review_texanomies&post_type=review